# How to use react-simple-keyboard with react-table?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have a reactjs app and i use it with a touchscreen. I need to implement the use of react-simple-keyboard with react-table.

I tried a lot of things but it seems like I can't find how to do that easily.

This is the kind of table I have: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/archives/v6-examples/react-table-custom-filtering

When I click an input, I make the keyboard show. If I use my physical keyboard, I can fill type letters in the input. But I can't manage to connect react-simple-keyboard to it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-keyboard

```js
    Header: '',
        id: "name",
        accessor: d => d.name,
        filterMethod: (filter, rows) =>
          matchSorter(rows, filter.value, { keys: ["name"] }),

                 Filter: ({ filter, onChange }) => {
                    return (
                        <input value={keyboardvar} />
                    );
                  },
        filterAll: true,
```

This let's me edit the value of the input, when I type I see it in the input, but there is no filtering happening.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Hey Francis, did you manage to solve this? If not, feel free to share an updated sandbox with the issue and I'll take a look!